# Database design: two related tables in a Database both reference a third table. How to ensure the three relations are coherent?

Tags: database, database-design

In my database I have three tables which look like these:

```
companies
+------------+
| company_id |
+------------+

agents
+----------+------------+
| agent_id | company_id |
+----------+------------+

customers
+-------------+----------+------------+
| customer_id | agent_id | company_id |
+-------------+----------+------------+
```

where the first id of every row is the primary key of the table.

These are the rules:

- each company has many customers
- each company has **zero or many** agents
- each agent works for exactly one company
- each agent deals with many customers
- each customer buys from exactly one company (assume so)
- each customer **may** be assigned an agent who deals with them

Property `company_id` in the `customers` table can be technically computed if the customer is assigned an agent (first we look for the agent_id of the customer and then the company_id of that agent).
However if the company has no agents **OR** if the customer is not assigned an agent, then `company_id` has to be explicit in the `customers` table.

How can I design my database so that `customers.company_id` is coherent with `agent.company_id` with `agent` coming from `customers.agent_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would define a unique key in `agents` combining the `company_id` and `agent_id`.  Something like this:

```
alter table agents add constraint unq_agents_company_agent
    unique (company_id, agent_id);
```

Then you would define a foreign key from customers:

```
alter table customers add constraint fk_customers_agents
    foreign key (company_id, agent_id) references agents (company_id, agent_id);
```

[The above syntax is pretty generic, but it might depend on the database.]

This should ensure the conditions that you have specified.